# Page is not loading correctly in wph application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have an application and created a RichTextBox in my page1 for my Windows Phone Application. The UI displays the way I want in the design box but when I try to run the application I get an error "EventHandler 'PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded' not found on class 'PhoneApp1.Page1'"

I don't understand what's going on at all and I thought maybe I was suppose to handle the actual display of the richtextbox in the coding cs section where I handled the button click to get to that page. When I look online all I see is how to use the richtextbox Like I have did on my xaml file. Any ideas what does that error mean?

Here is the code from my xaml and cs file:

```
namespace PhoneApp1
{
public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

and the xaml corresponding to the cs is:

```
  Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <RichTextBox VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold FontSize="32">Great Stuff</Bold>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
            Great Stuff
                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph> 
                <Bold FontSize="32">More Stuff</Bold>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
               More Stuff
                <LineBreak></LineBreak>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                <Bold FontSize="32">Some Stuff</Bold>
            </Paragraph>
            <Paragraph>
                Some Stuff
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no problem with your code .

search your solution , does a event "PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded" exist?

Comment: Thanks. It was automatically loaded that event. I don't know why but removing it from the xaml file fixed the issue.